# hashing points of elliptic curves

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves

Can I create a secure hash function $h: E(\mathbb{F}_p) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_q$ (for some $q$) where $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is an elliptic curve on the finite field of $p$ elements?
By *secure hash function* I mean: one way, strongly collision free.

Comment: I just have to ask — Why don't existing, well-vetted hash algorithms satisfy your needs?

Comment: Uhm, hash the representation?

Comment: @SEJPM can you define "representation"?

Comment: @richard the standard representation of a point in RAM, ie as ASN.1 paired big-endian integers (or whatever the relevant standards say).

Comment: @SEJPM You may have to perform mod $q$ afterwards. Furthermore, the result will not be perfectly distributed. The question is, does it have to be? It's certainly one way and strongly collision free. Oh, and you can simply use a compressed or uncompressed point representation, there doesn't seem to be a particular *need* to encode in ASN.1 - although equally viable.

Comment: @SEJPM  From a ECC virgin, isn't a hash of the _representation_  just a PRNG?  How would I use this construct to hash my CV?  Are you suggesting deriving a curve from my Word document?  I've got the wrong end of it haven't I?

Comment: @PaulUszak Hashing the representation of an elliptic curve  point is about as much a PRNG as is hashing a normal finite field element. You transform both into a well-defined representation and then hash the bytes.

Comment: @SEJPM I know nothing about RAM and in general about what you call a _point representation_. Can you explain it with an example? So, say we have a point $(a,b) \in E$, how would you map it to a number (so that I can hash this number with a standard hash function) ?

Comment: Hash functions take bits and bytes, so you need to map it to bits / bytes. In general an EC point consists of at least two numbers so it is a bit tricky to convert those into one number. Bits/bytes is easy though.

Answer (score 1):

With the current requirements, it seems like any member of $H(C(P)) \bmod q$ should work.

Where:

- $H$ is the set of secure hash functions, e.g. SHA-512;
- $C$ is the set of canonical encoding schemes of the points, e.g. a compressed point representation (02+X or 03+X depending if Y is odd or not);
- $P$ a the set of possible points on the curve;
- $q$ is the order of the curve (already specified).

This is certainly one way and collision free, as long as the used curve and hash function outputs are large enough. But note that it is *not* well distributed over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ (especially if the hash is shorter than $q$ of course, when viewed as an unsigned number).

Comment: I suppose that X is within \[0,Q\) and that a compressed point means that Y is either 02 or 03 (which can be represented by a single bit). So with that in mind you could use the answer of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24284/1172) to use FPE to create a well distributed point I guess. But I'm not all that sure that it is OK distribution-wise.

Comment: If you need a uniform distribution, then replace the $H$ with an XOF (e.g. SHAKE), have the XOF generate a stream of bits, and use one of a number of techniques to convert that stream of bits into a $\mathbb{Z}_q$ value

Comment: Interesting idea. I presume you can use the same techniques as generating a random number in a range to create the value.

Comment: True; typically, we don't care enough about a precisely uniform value to go to that effort, but we could...