# How to map the points of an elliptic curve cyclic group to $\mathbb{Z}_q$ using a hash function?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, finite-field

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathrm{GF}(q)$, where $q=p^r$. Let $G$ be a cyclic group of points of $E$. Then how we can map points of $G$ into $\mathbb{Z}_q$ using a hash function.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47189/hashing-points-of-elliptic-curves

Comment: Also see [this older Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37305/23623) and note that "whatever the standard you are following says" when applicable.

Comment: @SEJPM I have read the answer that you suggested me to read

Comment: @SEJPM Why are we using key derivation function in it ? I know nothing about it and have not used before...What I got from that answer is first, we have to apply a hash function e.g sha 512 and then we have to convert the output into an integer and take a mod on it to reduce the answer...Am I right or not ?

Comment: I think you are mostly right, but you might want to add two things. You should hash some *canonical representation* of the point, if you want to make sure that the same points hashes to the same element. Secondly, you might want to use around 128 bits *longer* of a hash output, before applying modulus (cfr. eg. NIST SP 800-185 Appendix B) to make the output more evenly distributed.