# How to map output of SHA to $\mathbb{F}_q^n$

Tags: hash, post-quantum-cryptography

I have an arbitrary string. I want to know how to implement a hash function $H: \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb F_q^n$ which takes arbitrary strings to an element of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. Here $\mathbb{F}_q$ denotes the finite field of order $q$.

Edit: $q=256$

Edit 2: $\mathbb F_q^n$ simply means $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$. If $x \in \mathbb F_q^n$, it means $x$ has the following form

$$x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n), \mbox{ with } x_i \in \mathbb{F}_q$$

Comment: Relevant: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88002/how-to-map-output-of-hash-algorithm-to-a-finite-field

Comment: It is not clear about $q=?$.  Another one https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87012/18298 and another https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86375/18298

Comment: [Revised for Edit2] Hint: What is [$\mathbb F_q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)? How many elements are there in $\mathbb F_q$? Thus in [${\mathbb F_q}^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_power)? How do you write $\mathbb F_q$ as $\mathbb F_{p^k}$? Thus how many bits do you need to represent an element of $\mathbb F_q$? Of ${\mathbb F_q}^n$? How do you get these bits with a hash of the SHA family?

Comment: @fgrieu Thank you for your hints. I will think about it and let you know as soon as possible. Thanks again for showing the right direction.